# RequireJS: loading different files according environment

Tags: javascript, requirejs, test-environments

Is there any functionality to load different files according on current project environment (development or production for example)? I mean something, that helps me transparently loading minified or full files. I read about multiversion loading, but multiversioning means that I need to specify version of file.

For example I have module.js file with my module. In this file I need to load jQuery:

```
require(['jquery]);
```

But I have minified and full version of jQuery and I want to load different files. I am thinking about something like this in config:

```
   require.config({
        paths: {
            'jquery' : function(){
                if( MODE == 'DEV' ){
                    return 'jquery';
                }else{
                    return 'jquery.min'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Or, maybe, something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone still want to know how to do that:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery' : (function(){
            if( MODE == 'DEV' ){
                return 'jquery';
            }else{
                return 'jquery.min'
            }
        })()
    }
});
```

This function is self invoking anonymous function. It invokes immediately in the definition place.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [the r.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) then this process can be taken care of for you. In your `scripts` folder leave all modules, libs and other code uncompressed for dev purposes. I often have something like this

```
scripts/
    lib/
    modules/
```

When ready to deploy, create a `build.js` and configure the various options. I'll give an example of a similar config I have used:

```
({
    baseUrl: '../scripts',
    dir: '../scripts.min',

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery'
    },

    removeCombined: true,

    optimize: 'uglify',
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    uglify: {
        max_line_length: 3500,
        no_copyright: true
    },

    modules: [
        {
            name: 'module1'
        },
        {
            name: 'module2',
            exclude: ['jquery']
        }
    ]
})
```

More details on each of this options [can be found in this example configuration](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) but I will draw attention to `dir` and `removeCombined`

`dir` is obviously where your scripts will end up. I tend to create a folder adjacent to my scripts with the suffix `.min` or something similar. Then, when you're ready to go to production, simply change your require config `baseUrl` to `scripts.min`

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/scripts.min' // Now the site will load scripts from the optimised folder

    // Other options
})
```

By default, r.js will copy all the scripts over regardless of whether they have already been combined into another js file or not. Setting the `removeCombined` to `true` will ensure your `scripts.min` folder only has the necessary files for production.